# How to patch class definition with mock in php?

Tags: php, class, mocking, patch

I mean something that acts like `unittest.mock.patch` in Python.

Is it possible in PHP?

**-- UPDATE1 --**

I'm using PHPUnit and try to mock the dependencies of SUT that is `LoginController`.

One of dependencies is the [Fatfree](https://fatfreeframework.com) `Base`. It's used directly in `LoginController`'s constructor as `Base::instance()`.

So, what I need is it to substitute the original `Base` class globally  with the my mock class object. To make SUT use mocked `Base::instance()`. The only way I found is to provide this mock object on constructor of `LoginController`. To make this I was obligated to change the orignial SUT code that doesn't consider unit test requirements.

But I don't like this, due to there are many places in SUT code where different dependencies are used. So I need to mock those in PHP "class registry" globally to force "client" code use my class definitions to create objects.

In couple of words I need to mock class definition on system-wide level.

I'm looking for several hours on the net and still can't find the solution.

```
class LoginControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $MockF3Base = $this->createMock(Base::class);
        $MockF3Base->method('get')->will($this->returnCallback(
            function($p) {
                $mock_params = [
                    'LANGUAGES'=>['en', 'ru'],
                    'COOKIE.lg'=>'en',
                    'user'=>new GuestModel(),
                    'AJAX'=>true,
                    'BASE'=>BASE_URL
                ];

                if (array_key_exists($p, $mock_params))
                {
                    return $mock_params[$p];
                }

                return null;
            }));

        $sut = $this->getMockBuilder(LoginController::class)
            ->setConstructorArgs([$MockF3Base])
            ->setMethods(['json_success'])
            ->getMock();

        $this->_sut = $sut;
    }

    public function testMustLoginIf__()
    {
       $this->_sut->expects($this->once())->method('json_success')->with($this->stringContains(BASE_URL.'/kassa'));
       $this->_sut->LoginAction();
    }

    private $_sut;
}
```

**-- UPDATE2 --**

Optional `$f3` constructor parameter is added by me. Originally it was just `$this->f3 = Base::instance();`

```
class LoginController{

    public function __construct($f3 = null){
        $this->f3 = is_null($f3)? Base::instance(): $f3;
        $this->section = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.section') or $this->section = 'index';
        $this->name = substr(get_class($this), 0, -10);
        $user = new GuestModel();
        $session = $this->f3->get('COOKIE.PHPSESSID');
        if($session && $user->load(['`session`=?', $session])){

        }
        $this->f3->set('user', $user);

        $language = $this->f3->get('COOKIE.lg');
        $language = array_key_exists($language, $this->f3->get('LANGUAGES')) ? $language : 'en';
        $this->f3->set('LANGUAGE', $language);

        if(!$user->dry() && ($user->session('language') != $language)){
            $user->session('language', $language, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about unit testing? The short answer is "yes", but the long answer totally depends on your context. Can you share an example of your code and the part where you want to mock a class?

Comment: This is the existing code I try to fixate.

Comment: Can you share the LoginController's constructor as well?

Comment: You can't globally replace a dependency that's hard-coded into a class.  If there's code in your class along the lines of `$object = new Foo()` or `$var = Foo::doSomthing()` then replacing Foo with a mock is essentially impossible.  If, however, you're using dependency injection then replacing Foo with a mock is relatively trivial with PHPUnit.  In your case you're referencing Base::* directly in the class and creating GuestModel instances, so replacing them is not going to be possible.

Comment: Someone in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436445/phpunit-how-to-test-a-method-which-calls-another-function-declared-in-different) referenced overriding a function using namespaces, which not being super PHP heavy myself, I couldn't implement OTOH by I can see how it's possible